# JavaScript Increment and Decrement Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I am trying to do a increment and decrement buttons. When the text value hit 24, it should stop increase. Here is the HTML codes:

```
<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
<input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
```

My CSS:

```
.qty {
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
input.qtyplus {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
input.qtyminus {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
```

And my JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // This button will increment the value
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
    // This button will decrement the value till 0
    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/845/). I get this fiddle by researching. I wonder is there any way to style the entire thing like plus button on top, followed by textbox and then minus button.

Also, is there any way to set the plus and minus limit by JavaScript? Because I did set a if ekse statement but it does not work.

Comment: simply put an if statement inside your if(!isNan(currentval)) checking the currentval and making sure it's less than 23

Comment: Did you try `type='number'`?

Comment: Yeah it works. But then how about the css? Cause I have no idea how to align the button and textbox vertically.

Comment: Their are multiple ways to align these items vertically, but I updated the fiddle with one of the simpler ways.
That is, put a break (<br />) between the input items in the html.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/848/

Answer (score 1):

put this code inside your `if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0)`

`if(currentVal === 24){
        return;
        }`

EDIT :
this way if the current value of you input box is 24 it will exit the function.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you originally pasted the "else if" part was not reached, because the "if (!isNaN..." part was already true. As VoronoiPotato suggested in the comments, you need to move the comparison elsewhere. For example:

```
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) ) {
        if (currentVal < 24) {
            // Increment
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
        }
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
```

Comment: Sure thanks. But as for the css part, is there any display css property that would align the html components in a div vertically?

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your jsFiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/847/

It is in your statement.. but i just wonder if you want to stop the last number to `24` or if the number reach `24` it will turn `0`.

In code here it will just stop in `24`

```
if (currentVal == 24) {
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal);
        }
        else if (!isNaN(currentVal) ) {
            // Increment
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
        } 
        else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
```

But is you want to turn the `24` back to `0` use this.

```
if (!isNaN(currentVal) && && currentVal<24 ) {
      // Increment
$('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
} 
else {
// Otherwise put a 0 there
$('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
}
```

I hope it will help you..